# creating variable that change

Tags: c, loops, variables, c99

This is part of my code:

```
float score_from_judge(number_judges, n) 
{ 
   float judge_score;    
   printf("Score from judge %d? ", n);
   scanf("%f", &judge_score);

   return(judge_score);
}

int main(void) 
{
   int n;
   float judge_score;
   n=1;
   for(n; n<=number_judges; n++ ) {
      judge_score = score_from_judge(number_judges, n)
   }
}
```

I am looking for a way to save judge_score in a variable every time score_from_judge returns the value.
I am trying to find a way to make a new variable for each loop.

For example, first time I recieve judge_score it is saved in variable_1 and next time in variable_2 etc.

Comment: 1) I think your code is missing a few brackets. 2) You want to learn about **arrays**.

Comment: Please make sure that your code compiles before posting it here. There are approximately 10 different errors in here!!!

Comment: Use arrays @tobblitz

Comment: Sorry, I just took the relevant parts out of the code and then I didnt put them together in the right way. Will think about that for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a float array and set its value inside the 'for' loop, as shown:

```
int main(){
    float judge_score[10];
    for(int n=1; n<=number_judges; n++ ) {
        judge_score[n] = score_from_judge(number_judges, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have declared `n` twice. And you probably want it to go from `0` to `number_judges-1`, if `number_judges` is 10.

Comment: I looked at the method he has defined, and I guess he's looking for a Judge #1 rather than a Judge #0

Comment: Thanks @SaranshKejriwal, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `float judge_score[number_judges+1]` would avoid a buffer overflow, in case number_judges is 10 or more